# I have installed the Protractor locally but still its pointing to global instance

Tags: protractor

I have installed the Protractor locally but still its pointing to global instance in MAC

I have set the path upto node_modules/.bin

Still its pointing to global instance.

I have protractor instance in global is 5.2.2

local protractor instance is latest version.

After setting the path also i see version as 5.2.2

Comment: your question is totally unclear. What do you want to ask? Where is question in your post?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you executed `npm install protractor` under `~/work`, there will be a folder `~/work/node_modules`.

If you execute `node_modules/.bin/protractor --version` under `~/work`, you will get the local protractor version.

If you want to use local protractor in terminal at any time, you can add `~/work/node_modules/.bin` at the heading of the current PATH environment value, So that the local protractor will be always first found in `PATH`.

I guess you add `~/work/node_modules/.bin` at the ending of the current PATH environment value, which make the global protractor be found at first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use npx https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx so when you run the protractor command it always points to the local version within your node_modules 
to run the command would be `npx protractor`